# Redis cluster support on various platforms

Tags: redis, cluster-computing

Are there any issues in setting up Redis cluster on various platforms like windows , Mac or Solaris. Currently Redis website says there is support for these platforms but I just want to know is there any caveat in cluster deployment on these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis cluster (i.e. v3) should be runnable on all supported platforms (i.e. *nix). The Windows version is not an official port but the last time I checked (now) it was still at v2.8 so I don't see how you could use the cluster with it.

Answer (score 0):

The MSOpenTech windows port of Redis has released a beta version 3.0 supporting Redis cluster:

https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases/tag/win-3.0.300-beta1